# How to add a button with border to storyboard in Xcode 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios8, xcode6

I wanna create a button with border in Xcode 6. For instance, I want it to look like the buttons from this library - https://github.com/a1anyip/AYVibrantButton - without any special visual effects. Is it possible to achieve this by doing some setup in IB without writing any code? Thanks.

Comment: Get two image, 1 is with transparent background and border, and 2nd one with background which you want, set both image in Storyboard button, in normal mode and highlight mode.

Comment: Border, corner radius and visual blur effects are runtime feature. In xcode you can only do it by code.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can add Runtime Attribute in storyboard

select your button

[image: Runtime Attribute in storyboard]

Comment: Thanks a lot but how do I change the width of the button?

Comment: I think I get it. Now is it possible to change the border color or some further properties?

Comment: Almost all property of button can be set here. Here is tech of KVC.

Comment: Thanks. Kind of ugly that there's no autocomplete for those properties in Xcode and you can't see the border until you run it.

Answer (score 7):

"addImageButton" here is my UIButton and I am using below lines of code to create border to the button.

```
 [addImageButton.layer setBorderWidth:5];
[addImageButton.layer setBorderColor:[[UIColor redColor] CGColor]];
[addImageButton setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[addImageButton setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

[image: Snapshot]

Hope this solves your issue.